# swap columns using sed

Tags: sed, swap

I have a data like below in file `test`:

```
2233:Jorge Bill :56Blue Pkwy  :99999
1111:Mary Smith :33Red Street :123456
```

I want to swap the family name and first name using sed and grouping but my code doesn't work!

```
sed 's/\([^:]*:\)\([^' ']*' '\)\([^:]*\)/\1\3\2' test
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape the single-quotes within your regex, and also you need to have one more forward slash at the end of your replacement string. I got rid of the single quotes, and here it is.

```
sed 's/\([^:]*:\)\([^ ]* \)\([^:]*\)/\1\3\2/' test
```