# How do I swap two strings using the sed command with the delimiter being a comma?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

this is my first time posting here so I apologize if the formatting is all weird.

Using the sed command, I want to swap x and y, from x,y into y,x and store the swapped version into a separate file.

The file I am supposed to modify contains,

```
#######bank info########
#
####name####    ####age####
#
Bob,Stevenson       27
David,Tan           43
Robert,Jackson      39
```

I want to change the name from firstname,lastname to lastname,firstname.

I have already tried using the command,

```
sed -e "s/^\([^#]*\) *\([,]*\)/\2\1/g" file > xxx
```

Yet when I examine the "swapped" file it looks like nothing has changed. Why?

The expected output is:

```
#######bank info########
#
####name####    ####age####
#
Stevenson,Bob       27
Tan,David           43
Jackson,Robert      39
```

But my output is:

```
#######bank info########
#
####name####    ####age####
#
Bob,Stevenson       27
David,Tan           43
Robert,Jackson      39
```

Which is exactly the same as the initial version. Why does this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swap columns using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378449/swap-columns-using-sed)

Comment: @oguz ismail Thanks for the reply! I am not sure how the code they provided works. sed 's/\([^:]*:\)\([^ ]* \)\([^:]*\)/\1\3\2/' test. Why do they have 3 of (\(...\))?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
   # only lines that do not start with a #
   /^#/!{
     # match from the start
     # match up until a comma
     # then match the comma
     # then match up until a space
     # swap the part before the comma and after comma
     s/^\([^,]*\),\([^ ]*\)/\2,\1/
   }
```

'

And a bit shorter verison:

```
sed '/^#/!s/^\([^,]*\),\([^ ]*\)/\2,\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see what I did wrong. I thought the ([^#]*\) meant match everything else except those that start with # since using ^ in a wildcard meant not whatever it is following it.

Comment: Sure, but also the `[^#]*` will match everything up until the `#`, but the `*` matches zero or more characters. So it can match _zero_ characters actually. I believe you can also `s/^\([^#,]\+\),\([^ ]*\)/\2,\1/`, but I felt like `/^#/!` is more explicit that we want to ignore comments. Cause it's easier ex. to `/^[ \t]*#/!` to ignore also comments that on lines that start with a space or tabs followed by `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as the very good answer by @KamilCuk, but using extended regex and word characters, you could do

```
sed -E '/,/s/(\w+),(\w+)/\2,\1/' file > newfile
```

Where `/,/` only operates on lines with a `','` and the capture groups of `(\w+)` match groups of one or more word-characters. The `(\w+),(\w+)` expression ensure there are two groups of word-characters separated by a comma, and then the `\2,\1` simply reinsert the back-references in reversed order, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -E '/,/s/(\w+),(\w+)/\2,\1/' file
#######bank info########
#
####name####    ####age####
#
Stevenson,Bob       27
Tan,David           43
Jackson,Robert      39
```

Comment: Ahhh this makes so much sense! I have not heard of (\w+) yet so this is very helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes it is, and all the extended regex niceties do help solve some of the problems with words and word-boundaries very nicely -- but, extended regex isn't available to all `sed`, so best to know how to use both `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`, this will do.

```
awk -F'[ ,]+' '/,/{$0=$2","$1"\t"$3}1' file
#######bank info########
#
####name####    ####age####
#
Stevenson,Bob   27
Tan,David       43
Jackson,Robert  39
```

It may be some easier to understand the `awk` in compare to `sed` :)

- `-F'[ ,]+'` Split line by one or more comma or space
- `/,/` for lines with comma do:
- `$0=$2","$1"\t"$3` reconstruct the line in new order with comma and tab
- `1` always true, do the default action, print the line.